# Event list data structure in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sortedlist

I need to implement an event list in python, where each element is an event that has an associated timestamps. The actions that I need to perform are essentially two: inserting in the right order (decreasing timestamps), and retrieving the event with the smaller start time.

I am aware of the bisect module, but it doesn't allow to insert arbitrary items in the list. For this reason I think that maybe I could implement the event list with two different python data structures:

- a bisect list containing all the timestamps
- a dictionary with the timestamps as the keys ans the events as value

Inserting and retrieving are straightforward.

Do you think that there is a more efficient approach?

Comment: [Heap queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) might be what you want.

Comment: ??? Have you tried `bisect.insort`? If you are trying to insert your own objects into the bisect, perhaps you just need to implement some comparison operators like `__le__` so that bisect knows how to sort your custom class instances. A while back I used simpy, a discrete simulation package, which used bisect in just the manner you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either go with [heap queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html), as @Bogdan suggests, or you can use [sched](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) for more advance purposes.